# Central Limit Theorem with (linear) weights

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

I have a question about the CLT. Suppose we have the independently and identically distributed random variables $X_i$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then, by the Central Limit Theorem

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\mu\right) \rightarrow N\left(0, \sigma^2\right)\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \rightarrow N(n\mu, n\sigma^2),
$$
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. But what if we have $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iX_i$, where $c_i$ are constants? Is it simply to say that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^nc_iX_i \rightarrow N\left(E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nc_iX_i\right], \;V\left[\sum_{i=1}^nc_iX_i\right]\right),
$$

that is,

$$
\sum_{i=1}^nc_iX_i \rightarrow N\left(\mu\sum_{i=1}^nc_i,\; \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2\right),
$$

or am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the meaning of a convergence in distribution to a normal distribution with **variable** mean and variance? The question applies to the convergence to $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$ at the beginning of the question as well as to the convergence you are trying to establish later on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. A sum (and a sample mean) converges to $n$ times variable mean and variance, no? Or do you mean that it has to be expressed in terms of convergence to a standard normal?

Comment: In probability as in other branches of mathematics, the statement that $x_n\to y_n$ has no meaning. The convergence of a sequence $(x_n)$ is expressed as $x_n\to y$, for some $y$ which does not depend on $n$. The two statements my previous comment addresses both fail this requirement.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. That makes sense and is something I didn't think about. Thank you for your help, and excuse my mathematical recklessness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be after central limit theorems *à la* Lindeberg or Lyapunov, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Central_limit_theorems_for_independent_sequences). These yield the convergence you are interested in, but stated more correctly, for example, some conditions ensuring that the sequence of general term
$$
\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nc_iX_i-\mu\sum\limits_{i=1}^nc_i}{\sigma\cdot\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nc_i^2}}
$$
converges in distribution to a standard normal distribution.